# RelativeLayout through code

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Output of my code.]I wrote some code for relativelayout in android but without xml and following is the code i used.

```
package layout.program;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Relativelayout extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.relativelayout);  

    RelativeLayout relativelayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView textview=new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("TopLeft");
    textview.setId(1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textviewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    textviewparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    relativelayout.addView(textview, textviewparams);

    TextView textview2=new TextView(this);
    textview2.setText("TopRight");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams2=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textviewparams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    textviewparams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    relativelayout.addView(textview2, textviewparams2);

    TextView textview3=new TextView(this);
    textview3.setText("BottomRight");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams3=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textviewparams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    textviewparams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    relativelayout.addView(textview3, textviewparams3);

    TextView textview4=new TextView(this);
    textview4.setText("BottomLeft");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams4=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textviewparams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    textviewparams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    relativelayout.addView(textview4, textviewparams4);

    TextView textview5=new TextView(this);
    textview5.setText("center");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewparams5=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textviewparams5.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    relativelayout.addView(textview5, textviewparams5);

    EditText edittext=new EditText(this);
    edittext.setHeight(90);
    edittext.setTextSize(18);
    edittext.setId(2);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams edittextparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    edittextparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,1);
    edittextparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
    relativelayout.addView(edittext,edittextparams);

    Button save=new Button(this);
    save.setText("SAVE");
    save.setId(3);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams saveparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    saveparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,2);
    saveparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    relativelayout.addView(save,saveparams);

    Button cancle=new Button(this);
    cancle.setText("CANCLE");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cancleparams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    cancleparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,2);
    cancleparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    relativelayout.addView(cancle,cancleparams);

    this.addContentView(relativelayout, layoutparams);
  }
```

}

The problem is i expected cancle button to align on right side but its aligning on left side and covering the save button... But what is the problem in my code.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try cancleparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
That should work.